# Struts2 - How do I invoke the prepare() method on page load?

Tags: java, struts2, interceptor

I want to invoke the `prepare()` method when a page loads in Struts 2.

It is my understanding that if I implement the `Preparable` interface on my action that the `prepare()` method should automatically fire when the page loads. Is this correct? Or is there any other configuration required?

I ask because this is what I have done and the prepare method only fires upon a button click, just before the execute method fires.

I want the prepare method to fire just after/before the page loads to populate an attribute on the action. How can I do this?

Comment: 1) Remove the exclusion of your method (that you put there, why ?);
2) Put a System.out.println("Foo has bars !") in your prepare() method as FIRST line; then tell us what is happening. As answered in your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437264/struts2-prepare-method-does-not-run-on-page-load), probably your prepare *is* running, and then going to error due to the parameter not initialized. Make sure u are using the Interceptor Stack I suggested you there. And do not touch it unless you know what you are doing...

Comment: @AndreaLigios 1) What do you mean remove the exclusion of my method? I have not indicated any exclusions... 2) Nothing is being printed out when the page loads. Prepare is running when I click a button.

Comment: I'm referencing at: "WARNING: Parameter [registerUser] is on the excludeParams list of patterns!"

Answer (score 3):

`prepare()` executes when a `Preparable` action is executed.

If it's not firing, then your `prepare()` method is either in the wrong action, you're not accessing the page through an action initially (e.g., hitting a plain JSP), or there's an interceptor stack configuration issue.

Comment: The prepare() method is on all my actions.. I'm not hitting a regular jsp page I am using the struts configuration <result name="registerSuccess">registerPage.jsp</result>. It must be a configuration issue. But how do I configure it?

Comment: I am getting a warning if that has anything to do with it: WARNING: Parameter [registerUser] is on the excludeParams list of patterns!

Comment: @stinkyPete Without further information it's impossible to help. With the normal stack you don't need to do anything at all for `prepare()` methods to fire.

Answer (score 1):

> It is my understanding that if I implement the Preparable interface on
>   my action that the prepare() method should automatically fire when the
>   page loads.

As per my understanding **this is not correct**. The prepare method is used to prepare some data to be used by the execute() method or any other worker method of the Action class and is thus called just before the worker method on the request from the Browser.

Invoking the prepare() method on page load would be programatically cumbersome and thus should be avoided. Try setting the attribute in other way

Hope this helps :)